# Why is font not displaying on my live website?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm hosting my portfolio on goDaddy and I've encountered this error:

'GET http://benjaminthomasgibbs.co.uk/JosefinSans-light.ttf 404 (Not Found)'

Or

'GET http://benjaminthomasgibbs.co.uk/JosefinSans-light.ttf main.html:63'

I haven't made any folders except for JavaScript. All my other fonts seem to be working and they're in the same root directory. I'm quite nooby when it comes to file paths - it's something I'm planning to research, so it could be an obvious error that I just can't see.

It's a 'TTF' file and I added the 'format('truetype')'.

Link to my portfolio: http://benjaminthomasgibbs.co.uk/

The font in question is for the main page where it says 'Junior Web Designer'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
@font-face {

font-family: main;
src: url("JosefinSans-light.ttf") format("truetype");

}
```

Comment: Would be nice if you linked any attempts you have made in code.

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to host it locally rather than reference it from Google Fonts? You can find the font here: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Josefin+Sans

Comment: @Amorris sorry I i edited it. Although it's answered now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your font was actually located at http://benjaminthomasgibbs.co.uk/JosefinSans-Light.ttf

Note the uppercase L.

Comment: Oh damn. Stupid mistake, thanks. Will mark as correct!

Answer (score 0):

This is not enough information to solve your problem, but with the amount of information available, your files are not being hosted where you think they are being hosted.

This may be because you did not setup the webserver (nginx/apache) to host the font assets. Or if you are using rails and want rails to serve it, then you need to enable this in your environmental/production file, setting rails to be the one that serves static files. Or whatever it relevant for your situation beyond that.

Comment: Guy above figured it out. Thanks for your input though pal.